# using of rand() function im mysql

Tags: mysql

i am using MySQL back-end and in one table there are records of similar id (id column is not primary key), and i want to fetch record randomly on the basis of different id i mean same id record will come together. Is it possible ?. if any body have any idea please share.

Thanks.

Comment: SELECT id,title,publishDate FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5

Comment: actually my condition is some different. Example like table contain record like that first row column id is 1 and name, 2nd row column id is 1 and name and 3rd row column id 2 and name .....like that. and i want the record will come randomly but same id column record came together. if i used random then record come randomly but column id which have same id not coming together means column id 1 have two record not coming together

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-rand-function.htm

mayb this can point you in the right direction

Comment: +------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-04-06 |                100 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
in the above table i want whenever i call rand() the same id column 3  come together means comes in consecutive row

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `id`,RAND( );
```

I think this will help you more.